# How to change a Wordpress term's slug before saving

Tags: wordpress, slug

We are using WP All Import to import product data from a CSV into WooCommerce. Everything works fine (great plugin!) but we have one problem:

Two of our product attributes contain disallowed symbols:

```
< 10 million views
> 10 million views
```

Wordpress automatically removes the '<' and '>' symbols meaning that the second attribute is treated as a duplicate and therefore doesn't get imported.

WP All Import's developers suggest using the wp_insert_term_data hook to change the slugs as they're being inserted into the database.

This is a good idea as we would then be able to maintain both attributes. For example:

```
< 10 million views becomes lt-10-million-views
> 10 million views becomes gt-10-million-views
```

I'm sure this is pretty simple, but I'm still a newbie when it comes to hooking into Wordpress! What's the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the needed function for your case:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_term_data', 'hook_term_332', 10, 3 );
function hook_term_332( $data, $taxonomy, $args ){
  //this is for slug part
  $data['slug']=sanitize_title($data['slug']);

  //this is for visible name part
  $data['name']=str_replace(array(">"), array("some_another_character"), $data['name']);

  return $data;
}
```

The function "sanitize_title" formats any string to acceptable slug. Usually it is used for sanitizing post titles and creating slugs for them, but it also fits to your case.